# DownloadStringAsync multiple URLs maintaining order

Tags: c#, html, url, asynchronous

I need to download multiple HTML pages as strings and store them into a list. But then need to be stored in the order i started the downloads. At the moment the list is in the order of download completion. So when a download finishes, its contents gets added to a list. But they dont necessarily finish in the order they were started. And im kinda stumped on how to store this data in a list in the order they were initiated.

Here is my current code, this initiates the download sequence. URLList is a list of urls, and i need the downloaded strings to be in the same order as this original list:

```
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    await AccessTheWebAsync(cts.Token);
    listBox1.DataSource = VideoList;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("\r\nDownload failed.\r\n");
}
cts = null;
```

Then that calls the following code:

```
async Task AccessTheWebAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");

    IEnumerable<Task<string>> downloadTasksQuery = from url in URLList select ProcessURL(url, client, ct);

    List<Task<string>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();

    while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
    {
        Task<string> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);

        downloadTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);

        string length = await firstFinishedTask;  //this is the data of the first finished download
        int refPoint = length.IndexOf("Download (Save as...): <a href=\"") + 32;
        VideoList.Add(length.Substring(refPoint, length.IndexOf("\">", refPoint) - refPoint));
    }
}

async Task<string> ProcessURL(string url, HttpClient client, CancellationToken ct)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);
    string urlContents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return urlContents;
}
```

Im sure its something rather simple. But i just need the downloaded strings to be in the same order as the original URLList list. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but this should work.

```
async Task AccessTheWebAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");

    var downloadTasks = new List<Task<Tuple<string, int>>();

    int index = 0;
    foreach(var url in URLList)
        downloadTasks.Add(ProcessURL(url, client, ct, index++));

    while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
    {
        Task<Tuple<string, int>> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);

        downloadTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);

        Tuple<string, int> result = await firstFinishedTask;  //this is the data of the first finished download
        int refPoint = result.Item1.IndexOf("Download (Save as...): <a href=\"") + 32;
        VideoList.Add(length.Item1.Substring(refPoint, length.IndexOf("\">", refPoint) - refPoint));
    }
}

async Task<Tuple<string, int>> ProcessURL(string url, HttpClient client, CancellationToken ct, int index)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);
    string urlContents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Tuple.Create(urlContent, index);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but getting some errors, I fixed 1 but not sure how to fix the other. I am still kind of new to C#. Its on the line "string length = await firstFinishedTask;"

Comment: I've updated the code. result.Item2 contains the index of the download task.